# how to input floating point numbers

Tags: java, input

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



  System.out.println("Enter a floating point number");

  float nA= java.util.Scanner.nextFloat();
  double nB= Math.pow(a, 3.5);

System.out.println("nB = nA^3.5" +nB);

  }
}
```

in this code im trying to allow the floating point number nA to be entered but im not sure how to

Comment: What is this language?

Comment: im using java (netbeans)

Comment: so add the java tag - that's how you will get more help

Comment: Does your code work? What's your question? What's `a`? Why aren't you using `nA`?

Comment: That code will allow `nA` to be entered, once you fix the compilation error about `a` being undefined. Perhaps you meant `nA`?

Comment: nah it says non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter a floating point number");

        float nA= input.nextFloat();
        double nB= Math.pow(nA, 3.5);

        System.out.println("nB = nA^3.5" +nB);


    }
```

Comment: i tried that but i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: try the edited version I dunno why are you getting that error what have you entered? also nextFloat() is a non-static method meaning it requires an object to be used and at Math.pow(double,double) but luckily java have automatic type conversion because double is higher than float float is automatically converted to double or you could also explicitly convert nA to double by Math.pow((double)nA,3.5);

Comment: I had seen you are still new to java I would suggest you read a book about java to fully understand each of the meaning of the code you are saying

Comment: what do you mean by requires an object?

Comment: it requires an Scanner object here the object is input and have you tried my code yet?

Comment: read a book entitled "Java Programming" by Joyce Farrell to change your life forever

Comment: ah true, and yea tried urs but still get the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter a floating point number");

        float nA= input.nextFloat();
        double nB= Math.pow(nA, 3.5);

        System.out.println("nB = nA^3.5" +nB); 


    }

Comment: yes and I don't understand why are you still getting that error on my notepad++ it work just fine, are you using looping?

Comment: that was the issue, i was using netbeans and i just used notepad++ and it works fine so idk what the issue was

Comment: maybe you did not entered a number then quickly press enter

Comment: if this answer your issue you can accept this answer by checking it

Comment: nah doesnt even let me enter on netbeans